# Integral $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}{d\theta\over (1-m^2\cos^2\theta)^2}$

Tags: integration, approximation

Can you help me to show that

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}{d\theta\over (1-m^2\cos^2\theta)^2} \approx {(2-m^2)\pi\over4(1-m^2)^{3/2}}$$

to first order, such that $0 \lt m \lt 1$

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, "to first order"?  Do you mean, to $O(m^2)$ on either side?  If so, then the LHS becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d{\theta} (1+2 m^2 \cos^2 {\theta})$$ 
which evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2} (1+m^2)$.  The RHS takes precisely this value upon a Taylor expansion to $O(m^2)$.

Comment: The exercise is the following: $f(m,\epsilon)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin^2\theta d\theta \over (1-m^2\cos^2\theta)^2sin^2\theta + \epsilon^2}$. I have split the integral into two parts at $\delta$ where $0 \lt \epsilon \ll \delta \ll 1$. I am trying to evaluate the global contribution where $\epsilon$ is negligible with error $O(\epsilon ^2)$. Does this help?

Comment: Sort of.  Still, I think you are not formulating the problem correctly, I think.  It seems to me that you are trying to find a simple, analytical expression for the original integral for all values of m that works within some error bound.  Adding the epsilon in the denominator isn't going to help in this case.

What will help is an expansion about m=0, and an expansion about 1/m = 0, and then a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over
\bracks{1 - m^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta} \over
\bracks{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta} - m^{2}}^{2}}\,
\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{2} + 1 \over
\pars{t^{2} + \epsilon}^{2}}\,\dd t
\,\right\vert_{\color{red}{\ {\large\epsilon}\ =\ 1 -\ m^{2}\,\, >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{1 - \epsilon}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{t^{2} + \epsilon}^{2}} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + \epsilon}
\\[5mm] = &
\bracks{\pars{\epsilon - 1}\partiald{}{\epsilon} + 1}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + \epsilon}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{\pars{\epsilon - 1}\partiald{}{\epsilon} + 1}
{\pi \over 2}\,\epsilon^{-1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi \over 2}\bracks{%
\pars{\epsilon - 1}\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\epsilon^{-3/2}} + \epsilon^{-1/2}}
\\[5mm] = &
{\pi \over 4}\pars{\epsilon^{-1/2} + \epsilon^{-3/2}} =
{\pi \over 4}\,{\epsilon + 1 \over \epsilon^{3/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\pi \over 4}\,{2 - m^{2} \over
\pars{1 - m^{2}}^{3/2}}}
\\[1mm] &\ \mbox{which is an}\ \underline{exact}\
\mbox{result !!!.} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{m^2\sin 2\theta }{1-m^2\cos^2\theta} \right)
= -\frac{2(2-m^2)}{1-m^2\cos^2\theta} +  \frac{4(1-m^2)}{(1-m^2\cos^2\theta)^2}
$$

Integrate both sides

$$0= -\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2(2-m^2)}{1-m^2\cos^2\theta}d\theta+ 
 \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{4(1-m^2)}{(1-m^2\cos^2\theta)^2}d\theta
$$

which leads to

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(1-m^2\cos^2\theta)^2}
&=\frac{2-m^2}{2(1-m^2)} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{1-m^2\cos^2\theta}\\
 &=\frac{2-m^2}{2(1-m^2)} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d(\tan \theta)}{\tan^2\theta +1-m^2}\\
&= {\pi(2-m^2)\over4(1-m^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}